# Dockerfile COPY command is missing a single file when using `gcloud build`

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-build

I have run into an incredibly frustrating problem where a COPY command in my Dockerfile successfully copies all of my apps files except one. I do not have a .dockerignore file so I know the file isn't being excluded from the build that way.

Note: I do have a `.gitignore` which is excluding `file2.json` that I do not want to version. But as you will see below, I'm building from my local folder, not remotely from a clone/checkout so I don't see why `.gitignore` would influence the docker build in this case.

Below is what my directory looks like:

```
$ tree -a -I .git app
app
├── app
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── file1.txt
│   │   ├── file2.json
│   │   ├── file3.txt
│   │   └── file4.yml
│   ├── somefile2.py
│   └── somefile.py
├── Dockerfile
├── .gitignore
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

And this is what is in my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3.7
  
COPY . /app
  
RUN cp app/app/data/file2.json ~/.somenewhiddendirectory
   
RUN pip install app/.
   
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app/app/somefile.py"]
```

For some reason, `file2.json` is not being copied during the `COPY . /app` call and I am getting an error when I try to `cp` it somewhere else. I have done a call like `RUN ls app/app/data/` and all the files except `file2.json` are in there. I checked the files permissions and made sure they are the same as all the other files. I have tried doing a direct `COPY` of that file which results in an error since Docker says that file doesn't exist.

On my system, that file exists, I can see it with `ls`, and I can `cat` its contents. I have played around with ensuring the context within the image is squarely within the root directory of my app, and like I said, all files are correctly copied except that json file. I can't for the life of my figure out why Docker hates this file.

For some added context, I am using Google's cloud build to build the image and the yaml config looks like this:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    id: base-image-build
    waitFor: [-]
    args:
      - build
      - .
      - -t
      - us.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/base/${BRANCH_NAME}:${SHORT_SHA}
        
images:
  - us.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/base/${BRANCH_NAME}:${SHORT_SHA}
```

and the command I am executing looks like this:

```
gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml . \
  --substitutions=SHORT_SHA="$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)",BRANCH_NAME="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
```

Comment: Did you check the permissions of `file2.json` don't differ? what gives the command `ls -l`?

Comment: BTW, the first `FROM` command of your Dockerfile is irrelevant (thumb's rule: a Dockerfile should only contain **one** `FROM`, unless you rely on [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) (which is not your case))

Comment: Yes I did. The file's permissions are `-rw-rw-r--` just like the other files in the same directory

Comment: Have you tried replacing `app/app/data/file2.json` with `/app/app/data/file2.json`.  Just in case you're in the wrong directory.

Comment: @FrankYellin yes, but again an `ls` shows all the other files except that one, so I don't think the file has been copied to begin with and since the `ls` command works, I'm sure I am pointing to the correct place.

Comment: What the heck. The source IS my git repo, but it a local pull of it, and the file is in the tree, just being ignored by git. Why would docker pay any attention to my .gitignore? Anyway, I removed the file from my .gitignore and now it works.

Comment: Add a .gcloudignore to overwrite the .gitignore file behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I have never used Google's cloud build so my answer is only based on read theory.*

---

> I don't see why `.gitignore` would influence the docker build in this case

Indeed, `docker build` in itself does not care about your `.gitignore` file. But you are building through Google's cloud build and this is a totally different story.

Quoting the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit) for the source specification in `gcloud build` command:

> [SOURCE]
> The location of the source to build. The location can be a directory on a local disk or a gzipped archive file (.tar.gz) in Google Cloud Storage. If the source is a local directory, this command skips the files specified in the `--ignore-file`. If `--ignore-file` is not specified, use `.gcloudignore` file. If a `.gcloudignore` file is absent and a `.gitignore` file is present in the local source directory, gcloud will use a generated Git-compatible `.gcloudignore` file that respects your `.gitignore` files. The global `.gitignore` is not respected. For more information on `.gcloudignore`, see `gcloud topic gcloudignore`

So in your given case, your file will be ignored even for a build from your local directory. At this point I see 2 options to workaround this problem:

1. Remove the entry for your file in `.gitignore` so that the default gcloud mechanism does not ignore it during your build
2. Provide a `--ignore-file` or a default `.gcloudignore` which actually re-includes the local file that is ignored for versioning.

I would personally go for the second option with something super simple like the following `.gcloudignore` file (crafted from the [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore))

```
.git
.gcloudignore
.gitignore
```